# Group by multiple rows in any order

Tags: mysql, select

I am using Mysql and PHP

If I have a table

```
-------------------
| no1 | no2 | no3 | 
|-----|-----|-----|
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|  B  |  C  |  A  |
|  C  |  B  |  A  |
-------------------
```

I would like to return the unique combinations of rows

```
SELECT `no1`, `no2`, `no3`
FROM  `items` 
GROUP BY `no1', `no2`, `no3`
```

I would like this to return only one row, as the combination of fields is the same if you ignore the order.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Your query return exactly your input table. Because if you grouped for all fields... you don't group!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two columns, this is easy:

```
select distinct least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
from t;
```

With three, this is a bit harder:

```
select distinct least(no1, no2, no3) as smallest,
       (case when no1 not in (least(no1, no2, no3), greatest(no1, no2, no3)) then no1
             when no2 not in (least(no1, no2, no3), greatest(no1, no2, no3)) then no2
             else no3
        end) as middle,
      greatest(no1, no2, no3) as biggest
from items;
```

Note that `distinct` is a more succinct way of getting distinct groups.

EDIT:

If you want to do this for more columns, MySQL doesn't offer the `nth()` function (analogous to `least()` and `greatest()`.  You can do the following.  Unpivot the values (assuming there is an id on each row), then use `group_concat()` with the `order by` option:

```
select distinct nos
from (select id, group_concat(noi order by noi) as nos
      from (select id,
                   (case when n.n = 1 then no1
                         when n.n = 2 then no2
                         when n.n = 3 then no3
                    end) as noi
            from items i cross join
                 (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
           ) nn
      group by id
     ) nn;
```

This will give you back the values as a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing a function used by your mysql server, the only thing I can think of is to use a combination of both SQL and PHP like this:

```
SELECT distinct
    `no1`, `no2`, `no3`
FROM  `items`
```

This will give the disinct rows, then we can do this trick. Pop it into an array and sort each row:

```
$array=(0 => 'C', 1 => 'B', 2 => 'A');
sort($array);
```

Gather all your new bits into a single multidimensional array and use a [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on them to only get the distinct values you want.

You could also replicate the same functionality of ordering the columns alphabetically in MYSQL though that wold no doubt be quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(`no1`, `no2`, `no3`) as STH
FROM  `items` 
GROUP BY `no1', `no2`, `no3`
```